# Probability of atleast 2 people out of n people, having same birthday on a particular date?

Tags: probability

So, I know the birthday-paradox problem, and for $n=23$ we have that probability of at least 2 persons out of n, having same birthday in a 365 day year is approx 51%. Suppose now I select a particular day say 10 Nov. Now, what should be the value of n so that the probability that at least 2 people out of n have same birthday on 10th Nov is at least 50% ? Would it be $n=23$ ?

Comment: No.  The probability that a particular person is born on 10 November is $1/365$ (if we ignore leap years).  Therefore, the expected number of people you would need to have a single person with that birthday is $365$.

Comment: Yeah, I know that.But what about atleast 2 people having birthday on that date?